# Updating Stats On-The-Fly Using Facebook's Graph API Real-Time Updates

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, callback

I am looking to use Facebook's Graph API to implement [real-time updates](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/).

My web app will start out as a basic front-end that says `[Page Name] has [x] likes.`  What I would like to accomplish is when a user likes the page, `[x]` will update accordingly and a message appears saying that the # of likes has increased.  I have already implemented getting the number of likes from a page.

Ideally, I would like the update to take place when the `POST` from Facebook to my callback URL is made.  A suggestion I received was to set up a listener for the callback, then once Facebook makes a `POST` to my callback URL, the listener will update data accordingly and interact with the front-end to update `[x]`'s value.

Is this possible? If so, how would I go about implementing such?  I am trying to avoid a polling technique as, in a large-scale context, would constantly use resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation for Real-Time updates, you can subscribe to likes by the users who has authorized your app.  Not to anyone who likes a page.  The page can get notified of only one thing: "*For page, you will get updates about the pages which have added your application as a tab.* ".  So this API is not going to have that ability.

My suggestion would be to use a polling technique to get your page's number of likes using FQL via the JS SDK.

`SELECT fan_count FROM page where page_id = {your page}`

Comment: Thanks. I am just testing functionality at the moment, so my next approach is to access my personal likes and update the number of my likes real-time from there.

Comment: I am no longer working on this project, but thank you for your help. Answer accepted.